# function not getting new value from input field unless page is refreshesd

Tags: javascript

I have some dynamically created input fields that allow the user to run multiple queries at once. The issue when I enter a search term into a field it works the first time and returns the relevant data but if I enter a different search term and run the search again my function does not research with the new term in the input field. I have to refresh the page to run a different search. Here is the code that retrieves the search term.

```
var searchTerms = [];

function getSearchTerm() {
  $(".buttonshowHide").show();
  for (i=0; i<searchBoxes; ++i) {
    var searchTerm=document.getElementById("gearInput" + i).value;
    searchTerms.push(searchTerm);
  }
    makeBtnLabels();
    buildRequestUrl();
};
```

The getSearchTerm function is triggered by pressing an html search button.

Comment: Are you reseting the search terms array in your `makeBtnLabels()` or `buildRequestUrl()` methods ?

Comment: We cannot help you without a complete example. Please read [mcve]. We don't know: what `searchBoxes` is; how/when `getSearchTerm` is called; how/where you are using `searchTerms`, and most importantly: what exactly you want to happen. *"my function does not research with the new term in the input field"* doesn't mean anything to us. E.g. a better problem description would be: "If I type in abc I expected to get/see ...., if I type in xyz afterwards I expected to get/see ....".